# Converter of SQL Server DB to Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

Is there any package, software or tool which does the following:

- Converts a SQL Server DB to Entity Framework Code First
- Makes the Domain Classes, DB Context and the connections string or
  just makes the domain classes of our entities and relations.

Comment: hi, please check out scottgu's blog post http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a feature in Visual Studio which allows you to create a Code First model from an existing Database.

Here is the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620

Under the heading "Reverse Engineer Model", see the notes about using the "Reverse Engineer Code First" feature.

Comment: Thanks, "Reverse Engineer Model" is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following tools:

[Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Visual Studio using [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

Take a look at step-by-step tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. that was useful too